# Data structure in Java that supports quick search and remove in array with duplicates

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, linked-list, duplicates

More specifically, suppose I have an array with duplicates:

```
{3,2,3,4,2,2,1,4}
```

I want to have a data structure that supports search and remove the first occurrence of some value faster than O(n), say if the value is 4, then it becomes:

```
{3,2,3,2,2,1,4}
```

I also need to iterate the list from head according to the same order. Other operations like get(index) or insert are not needed.
You can use O(n) time to record the original data(say it's an int[]) in your data structure, I just need the later search and remove faster than O(n).
"Search and remove" is considered as ONE operation as shown above.
 If I have to make it myself, I would use a LinkedList to store the data, and HashMap to map every key to a list of all occurrence of nodes together with their previous and next ones.
Is it a right approach? Are there any better choices already there in Java?

Comment: If it's an unsorted input data, you can never get better than O(n) to remove duplicates because you'll have to go through every single element to find out.

Comment: You can use O(n) time to set up the data structure, I need later search and remove to be faster.

Comment: OK, How about get a Set<int>, loop through the input data. If integer not in Set, write to output array and add integer into Set. At the end, you will have an output array with no duplicates and the order is preserved.

Comment: @anonymous A general `Set` isn't ordered, and none of the JRE implementations orders according to insertion.

Comment: I'm writing up an answer to your actual question, but if you described what you're accomplishing, there might be a more efficient way to handle it.

Comment: @chrylis, the Set is to store knowledge that "I've seen this number" not for result. But I just realized he wanted first occurrence of duplicate to be removed and not all duplicates.

Comment: @anonymous I want to keep the other duplicates and their positions as shown in the example, a Set<int> would lose these information

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what your use case is? I'm really tempted to tag this question `premature-optimization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you describe, essentially a hybrid linked list and map, I think is the most efficient way of handling your stated problem. You'll have to keep track of the nodes yourself, since Java's `LinkedList` doesn't provide access to the actual nodes. The `AbstractSequentialList` may be helpful here.

The index structure you'll need is a map from an element value to the appearances of that element in the list. I recommend a hash table from `hashCode % modulus` to a linked list of (value, list of main-list nodes).

Note that this approach is still O(n) in the worst case, when you have universal hash collisions; this applies whether you use open or closed hashing. In the average case it should be something closer to O(ln(n)), but I'm not prepared to prove that.

Consider also whether the overhead of keeping track of all of this is really worth the gains. Unless you've actually profiled running code and determined that a `LinkedList` is causing problems because `remove` is O(n), stick with that until you do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, profiling the code first is a good suggestion. At first I expect to learn some tricky shortcut in Java, like some kind of tree data structures? Since O(log(n)) is also welcome. Anyway I will choose your answer.

Comment: If you supply an algorithm that uses hashing, then you always suspect the hashfunction to be out of a family of univseral hashfunctions. The expected runtime of the algorithm @Bamqf explained would then be O(1) wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is that the first occurrence of the element should be removed and the remaining occurrences retained, there would be no way to do it faster than O(n) as you would definitely have to move through to the end of the list to find out if there is another occurrence. There is no standard api from Oracle in the java package that does this.

Comment: There was no requirement stated to retain a last occurrence of an element.

Comment: No he has clearly mentioned that the first occurrence needs to be eliminated and has provided an example - according to him, the last occurrence needs to be retained

Comment: Yes to the first. The "retain the last occurrence" doesn't show up *anywhere* in the question.

Comment: Hmm.. from his example it looks like that is what he wants. Maybe he didn't say it in those exact same words but his example demonstrates it.

Comment: No, his example demonstrates "remove the first occurrence". If the first occurrence had been the only one, then it would have been removed.

Comment: Sorry I made this question vague, I mean you can use O(n) time to go through the data and take necessary record of all occurrences of all value, I just want the later search and remove faster.